# slideToggle numerous elements on a page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a map of a state with off of its counties sliced up as an image map.  Instead of having a different function to click on each county and show its statistics is there a way to use something other than:

`$('#county).click(function(){$(#countystats).slideToggle('fast');` 100+ times for all the different counties?

Comment: I don't understand - do you want to programatically trigger the `click`? If so, you can use `$('#county').trigger('click');` On the other hand, if you want all of the stats elements to slide at once, you could add a class to all and use that as the selector - `$('.countyStats').slideToggle('fast')`

Comment: no, say there are three counties a, b, c.  instead of writing three different javascripts to slidetoggle all three of them i was wondering if there was a way i could write one function that recognized the id or class of each county and have the slideToggle work.  instead of having to write 100 versions of the above script.

Comment: i don't want all of them to slide at once.  i was just wondering if it was possible to have one function that would work one at a time for all of the different elements on the page.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you have multiple elements that need to be styled the same or that you might need to pick up as a 'group', you can use a class instead of an id.

So if you want to attach a click handler to *all* county elements, you could add a `class` attribute to each `div` or `span` or whatever and use that as the selector.

```
$('.county').click(function(){
          $(this).find('.countystats').slideToggle('fast')
});
```

What this does is attach a click-listener to every element on the page that has  `class='county'` (for example, `<div class='county'>` or even `<img class='county'>`) and on click of that element, toggles it's descendent element with the `countystats` class.

I'm assuming here that you have a separate `countystats` element for each. If instead you have *one* `<div>` with the `id` `countystats`, you can keep your original call

`$('#countystats').slideToggle('fast');`

but note that it looks like it will cause the `countystats` to be toggled off with a second click so you probably want to change how that's handled. For example, I click on county 1, the stats slide into view. I click on county 2, the same handler is fired so the element is *toggled off*.